# How to make this code more clear and flexible?

Tags: php, coding-style, refactoring

The task is to calculate money cost based on passed distance.
Here is tariff plan:

1. 1-100 kilometres evaluates to 105 USD
2. 100-300 km evaluates to 55 USD
3. 300-any evaluates to 30 USD

If passed distance is 305 km then the money cost is 100 km by 105 USD + 200 km by 55 USD + 5 km by 30 USD = 100 * 105 + 200 * 55 + 5 * 30 = 21650 USD

Any suggestions how to improve below code?
I really want it to be flexible, clear and fast. The tariff plan can grow at any time to big sizes (more records). I really don't like the foreach loop but I don't come with up else.

```
$distance = 305;
$prices = [
     105 => [1, 100],
     55 => [101, 300],
     30 => [301, 99999],
];
 $cost = 0;
 for ($i = 1; $i <= $distance; $i++) {
     foreach ($prices as $price => $kilometres) {
        if ($i >= $kilometres[0] && $i <= end($kilometres)) {
            $cost = $cost + $price;
        }
     }
 }
 $over_km = $distance - 99999;
 if ($over_km > 0) {
    $cost = $cost + $over_km * 30;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
    $distance = 305;
    $pricing = [
        [
            'threshold' => 100,
            'price' => 105
        ],
        [
            'threshold' => 300,
            'price' => 55
        ],
        [
            'threshold' => PHP_INT_MAX,
            'price' => 30
        ]
    ];

    $price = 0;
    $offset = 0;

    foreach ($pricing as $priceinfo) {    
        $delta = ($distance + $offset > $priceinfo['threshold']) ? $priceinfo['threshold'] - $offset : $distance;
        $price += $delta * $priceinfo['price'];
        $distance -= $delta;
        $offset += $delta;
        if ($distance == 0) break;
    }
    echo $price;
```

Use a series of thresholds, and adjust the pricing when the thresholds are met.